# Determining select from select multiple

Tags: selenium, xpath

This may have a simple answer but I could not find an answer by searching.  I am using Selenium with Java.

I have several elements (WebElement ele).  I locate them by means other than their direct tag names so I cannot simply use the xpath to answer the question I have.

I have several possible element types:

```
<div>
<input>
<input type = "checkbox">
<select>
<select multiple>
```

I can determine most of them.  If I do *ele.getTagName()*.  If it is a *div* I will know right away.  If it is *input* I can do a ele.getAttribute("type") and see whether it is checkbox or not.  But for *select* the tagname will give me select both for the regular *select* and the *select multiple*.  There is no attribute name for the multiple, so how can I distinguish between *select* and *select multiple* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
//if its a select element
Select se = new Select(ele);
```

Then you could simple check if this is a multi select element by running:

```
se.isMultiple()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XPath` expression to choose `select` *with* `multiple` attribute:

```
//select[@multiple]
```

or `select` *without* `multiple` attribute:

```
//select[not(@multiple)]
```

Also note that even without explicit *value* of `multiple` attribute, actual value is `"true"`, so if `multiple` attribute present in `select`, `ele.getAttribute("multiple")` should return `"true"`